# llenar input multiselect select2

Tags: jquery, select2

Estoy buscando por todas partes y no consigo encontrar como puedo llenar un input de un select multiple que usa select2.

el codigo que estoy usando es este:

```
if (ui.item.tallas >= 1) { $('#'+Talla).val(ui.item.talla.split(',')).trigger('change'); $('#'+Talla).select2("val", ui.item.talla.split(',')); } //compruebo que hay tallas
```

lo llamo 2 veces para probar si alguna de las dos formas lo hace, pero nada ni una ni otra.

el select que uso es este:

```
<select tabindex="14" name="InPedido_Talla[]" id="InPedido_Talla" style="width: 80px;" class="multibuskiselect multibuskiselect_InPedido" multiple="multiple">
```

y los datos recibidos vienen de mysql separados por coma. por eso el split.

¿Como podría insertarle esos valores al input?

Comment: No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta, estos últimos días estuve llenando inputs y campos option de un select mediante Jquery que venían desde una db, si me das mas información quizas puedes hacerlo de la manera que lo hice yo, por Ajax

Comment: Hola @felipeandrade a ver, los datos los tengo y los traigo con ajax y json. en principio si el select no es multiple funciona, falla al ser multiple que no trae nada. el valor de ui.item.talla son números separados por coma 15,16,34,32 etc. Solo me falta que me inserte esos datos en un select multiple que usa selelect2

Comment: var mes = json.message; //mensaje que trae de vuelta los datos de la consulta,    
    for (var i = 0; i < mes.length; i++) {
          $('#'+Talla).append('<option class="opcion" value="' + mes[i][0] + '">' + mes[i][0] + '</option>');
        }

Tambien debieras intentar con el if de esta forma(ui.item.tallas <= 1) para verificar que el problema no sea la condicion

Answer (score 1):

No se si he entendido bien tu pregunta pero esto seria lo mas aproximado que entiendo que estas buscando hacer, espero que te sirva, saludos

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   var ui = {
       item: {tallas: "15,16,34,32"}
   };

   var tallasAux = ui.item.tallas.split(',');

   if (tallasAux.length >= 1) { 

    for (var i = 0; i < tallasAux.length; i++) { 

     $('#selectTallas').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+tallasAux[i]+'</option>' );

    } 

   } 

});
```

```css
#selectTallas{

  width:80px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="select" id="selectTallas"></select>

</body>
</html>
```